# Find sequences in vector that do not match a pattern

Tags: r

I want to find sequence of elements in vector that do not match a pattern.
For example:

```
pattern <- c(1,2,3,4)
test <- c(5,4,3,6,1,2,3,4,5,3,3,2,1,2,3,4,6,3,7,5,1,2,3,6)
```

I want to find whole sequence in "test" that do not match "pattern" or indexes where this situation occurs.
So I want to get a result similar to this:

```
> want
[[1]]
[1] 5 4 3 6

[[2]]
[1] 5 3 3 2

[[3]]
[1] 6 3 7 5 1 2 3 6
```

or something like this:

```
> indexes
[1]  1  9 17
```

Do you have an idea how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is

```
lapply(scan(text=gsub(paste(pattern,collapse=""), ",",
     paste(test, collapse="")), what="", sep=",", quiet = TRUE), 
     function(x) as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(x, ""))))
#[[1]]
#[1] 5 4 3 6

#[[2]]
#[1] 5 3 3 2

#[[3]]
#[1] 6 3 7 5 1 2 3 6
```